# FQL time timezone offset wrong?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I've been pulling some info from Facebook status feed and I'm just wondering why I need to add 7 hours to the times to match up with my timezone? Normally I'm +10 and with daylight savings I would be +11 so I'm not sure why 7 hours works?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possibilities.  If -7 hours equals PST than you're receiving data in Facebook's (sometimes) default timezone -- from Palo Alto, CA.  If it is something else you may want to see if it matches the location/timezone for the location of the user account.